# Blogger get part of text body post

Tags: themes, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

0

I was creating a blogger theme and I intend to have a card layout with the first image and a text-only summary (fixed characters followed by ...) in the post list.

I could get the first image of the post using data:post.firstImageUrl attribute.
I would like to know how I can retrieve a specific string in the text of the post, for example a price, to place it above the image in the post list, can someone give me an idea of how I could do it?

[some like this.......](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9J2d.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.